# JAXB Moxy mixed whitespace lost

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, whitespace, moxy

I have a problem while unmarshalling an XML with mixed content. A space gets lost. The XML looks like this:

```
<text>rooms in <g>the</g> <g>Eldorado Hotel</g> on Broadway have a jacuzzi</text>
```

This is unmarshalled to:

- "rooms in " (with a final space)
- a  object with value 'the'
- a  object with value 'Eldorado Hotel'
- " on Broadway have a jacuzzi" (with an initial space)

Everything is fine but I'm missing the space between the two  tags. I need to preserve that space!

The simplified mapping would be something like:

```
@XmlTransient
public abstract class AbstractText {

    private List words;

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(type = WordGroup.class, required = false), // this is the <g> tag
        @XmlElementRef(type = Word.class, required = false)
    })
    public List getWords() {
        if (words == null) words = new ArrayList();
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(List words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

}

@XmlRoot
public class Text extends AbstractText{

}
```

The mapping is not done exactly like this, but in an XML file (each class inherinting from AbstractText can have different children.

The real mapping is:

```
<java-type name="dp.dc.exercise.model.Text">
    <java-attributes>
        <xml-element-refs java-attribute="words" xml-mixed="true">
            <xml-element-ref type="dp.dc.exercise.model.text.Word" required="false"/>
            <xml-element-ref type="dp.dc.exercise.model.text.WordGroup" required="false"/>
        </xml-element-refs>
    </java-attributes>
</java-type>
```

and works great in everycase but when there are 2 tags, one after the other.

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What does your mapping look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, I have entered the following issue that you can track:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/453934